# JVM returns with -1073741819 when loading native library

Tags: java, c++, dll, shared-libraries, native

So I am trying to load a native library from a resource contained in the resources of the JAR. I'm using some code to select the correct `.dll` file based on the current platform. (my platform is Windows 10 on `amd64`) It then extracts the code to a temporary file and passes the absolute path to `System.load(String)`. ([Code of Natives.java (Utility)](https://pastes.dev/von0cAah6t)). I am calling this from a `static { }` block in the class supposed to load its own natives. When calling a test `main(String[])` method in that class to test the loading of the libraries, it extracts the correct `.dll` file and attempts to load it, then it crashed and exits with `-1073741819`, I have searched for this exit code on Google but I can't seem to find any information on this, not even outside of Java.

With breakpoints I was able to conclude that it happens somewhere in `System.load`, because before that call everything works, and after it has stopped so its never reached.

All resources, including the C++ source code, Python build system I made to build it, the built `.dll` files (under `src/main/resources`) and the code for the loading and utility class can be found here: [GitHub](https://github.com/orbyfied/j8/tree/master/j8-math-expr)

**Edit:** I have used the Microsoft `dumpbin /EXPORTS` tool on it, this is the result: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ikEr.jpg)

> **Minimal Reproducible Example**

To reproduce this you really only need to:

> **1:** Copy the `Natives.java` file provided above ([Code of Natives.java (Utility)](https://pastes.dev/von0cAah6t)) into your source directory

> **2:** Copy the built DLL matching your system (32 or 64 bit) from [here](https://github.com/orbyfied/j8/tree/master/j8-math-expr/src/main/resources/natives) into a directory `natives` under your resource folder

> **And 3:** Create a simple main file with the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Natives.loadNativeFromResource(Main.class, "j8mathexpr_native");
}
```

Your project structure should now look something like this:

```
src
 - main
   - java
     - Main.java
     - Natives.java
   - resources
     - natives
       - j8mathexpr_native-xx-win.dll
```

Comment: This is an access violation. Use this helpful site to decode error codes: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741819](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741819)

Comment: *it extracts the correct .so file* But that's *not* a WIndows binary, it's a Unix one. You need a dll on Windows

Comment: i modified the build script to build to a .dll file, still doesnt work

Comment: Oh OK. I'd probably test the dll with native tools independently of Java first to make sure it's sound

Comment: I have used the Microsoft `dumpbin /EXPORTS` tool on it, this is the result: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/zCr6ziF)

Comment: That's promising. I'm now going to leave it for the C* people

Comment: There's an awfully large amount of files. Please create a small app with a *main* method that loads the lib and calls some functions. Please create a[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added a guide to a minimal reproducible example